# Ending the Apache rewrite-engine after a certain rule is matched

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to rewrite all request paths to my initiation file. Like so:

```
RewriteRule .* framework/init.php
```

Except, within this framework there are some directories from which files may be served without having the request to be handled by PHP. However, I don't want to use the actual path to these directories, because I want to be able to have these paths interpreted by the PHP router.
Therefore I'd like to have aliases for these directories. For example:

```
RewriteRule ^i/com/(\w+)/(.*)$ framework/components/$1/images/$2
```

Now the problem is, that both of these rewrite rules work individually, but when I try to combine them, things go wrong. It looks like it reevaluates my entire .htaccess after the alias rewrite has occurred. Here are some examples of what I tried:

**Skipping the rewrite-everything line under certain conditions:**

```
rewriteRule ^i - [S=1]
RewriteRule .* framework/init.php
RewriteRule ^i/com/(\w+)/(.*)$ framework/components/$1/images/$2
```

Does not work. It appears like the second line gets skipped, then the third line rewrites to a condition where the second line does not get skipped, so then the second line executes.

---

**Using an exclusive rewrite-everything line:**

```
RewriteRule (?!i).* framework/init.php
RewriteRule ^i/com/(\w+)/(.*)$ framework/components/$1/images/$2
```

Same story.

---

**Stopping the rewrite engine after the exception line:**

```
RewriteRule ^i/com/(\w+)/(.*)$ framework/components/$1/images/$2 [L]
RewriteRule .* framework/init.php
```

Not working.

---

**Adding a rewrite condition:**

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(?!i)
RewriteRule .* framework/init.php
RewriteRule ^i/com/(\w+)/(.*)$ framework/components/$1/images/$2
```

---

Note that all of the above examples start working when I remove one of two RewriteRules. I've looked for similar questions, but they all have solutions that I tried to apply. The one difference between their questions and mine, is that I want to rewrite my "special" directory to a directory that, when normally requested, would result in a rewrite to init.php. Can anyone tell me if this is at all possible, and if so, what I am missing or not getting?

Comment: what i understand you don't to rewrite request under framework/ to your init.php and all other requests to route through init.php?

Comment: No. I want to rewrite requests to /i/[something] in a specific way to a specific folder, and all other requests to /framework/init.php. The folder I'm rewriting the /i/ requests to will be one that can't normally be requested, as that normal request would be rewritten to init.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution today. I set an environment variable when the `^i`-rule is matched, and check if that environment variable is set later. If it is, I skip the `.*`-rule. Like so:

```
RewriteRule ^i/com/(\w+)/(.*)$ framework/components/$1/images/$2 [E=REWRITE:1,L]
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_REWRITE} !1
RewriteRule .* framework/init.php
```

It might be a little ugly. But it works like a charm in older versions of Apache.

Answer (score 0):

After doing [some research](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_l) I found out that the rewrite engine does in fact reevaluate a path after in has been rewritten:

> It is possible that as the rewritten request is handled, the .htaccess file or  section may be encountered again, and thus the ruleset may be run again from the start. Most commonly this will happen if one of the rules causes a redirect - either internal or external - causing the request process to start over.

And I should use the [END] flag in order to completely stop the rewrite engine.

> An alternative flag, [END], can be used to terminate not only the current round of rewrite processing but prevent any subsequent rewrite processing from occuring in per-directory (htaccess) context. This does not apply to new requests resulting from external redirects.

However, this [END] flag is [new since Apache 2.4](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/new_features_2_4.html).

> mod_rewrite adds the [QSD] (Query String Discard) and [END] flags for RewriteRule to simplify common rewriting scenarios.

So the conclusion is: Unless I have Apache 2.4, which I don't, it can't be done.

EDIT: I'm going to leave this answer "unchosen", for when somebody knows the "old" way of doing it.